# Performing one SQL command on multiple tables (without re-writing the SQL command)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a series of SQL commands I would like to run on about 40 different tables.  There must be a way to do this without writing 40 different commands...

I am running this in SQL Server.  All tables have different names, and the column I want to manipulate (VariableColumn below) also varies in name.  I do have a list of the names for both the tables and the columns.

The end effect of this code: I am connecting VariableColumn as a foreign key to the DOC_ID column in the DOCS table.  Some tables have values in their VariableColumn that do not correspond to any in the DOC_ID column (outdated data), so I am first deleting any such rows.

The command:

```
-- Delete rows in VariableTable that have invalid VariableColumn values
DELETE FROM VariableTable
FROM VariableTable v
LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCS d
    ON d.DOC_ID = v.VariableColumn
WHERE d.DOC_ID IS NULL

-- Add foreign key to VariableTable table
ALTER TABLE VariableTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DOCS_VariableTable_VariableColumn FOREIGN KEY (VariableColumn)
    REFERENCES DOCS(DOC_ID);
```

Comment: Generate your sql commands dynamically and execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have the list of table and column names you can have them in a table. And you can use them in a cursor to build and execute your commands.

For example:

```
DECLARE @Target TABLE (tbl SYSNAME,col SYSNAME)
INSERT @Target VALUES ('tbl_1','col_a'),('tbl_2','col_b')

DECLARE @tbl SYSNAME
DECLARE @col SYSNAME
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE work CURSOR FOR  
SELECT tbl,col
  FROM @Target

OPEN work   
FETCH NEXT FROM work INTO @tbl,@col   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       SET @sql = 'PRINT ''Do something to table: ' + @tbl + ' column: '+ @col + ''''       
       EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
       FETCH NEXT FROM work INTO @tbl,@col   
END   

CLOSE work   
DEALLOCATE work
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a one off batch you want to run, you could generate this with a simple generator such as NimbleText (http://NimbleText.com/Live)

The data is a list of the tables and columns you want to edit, e.g.

```
Person, PersonID
Document, DocumentID
Vehicle, VehicleID
etc...
```

The pattern is like this:

```
-- Delete rows in $0 that have invalid $1 values
DELETE FROM $0
FROM $0 v
LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCS d
    ON d.DOC_ID = v.$0
WHERE d.DOC_ID IS NULL

-- Add foreign key to $0 table
ALTER TABLE $0 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DOCS_$0_$1 FOREIGN KEY ($1)
    REFERENCES DOCS(DOC_ID);
```

Press "Calculate", Grab the result and execute it in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial PowerShell to modify a template SQL file and SqlCommand come to my mind. Not yours?

Answer (score 0):

This seems just like an stored procedure, I've never used them in sql-server but you can check how-to in [MSDN Stored procedures guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669.aspx)